# Select 5 rows if they are not in top 3

Tags: mysql

I want to select 5 articles from table that are not 3 newest.

Here is how I get 5 articles from the table named article:

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE FOREIGN_ID_MENU = '".$id."' AND active = '1' ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 0, 5;
```

And how I get the top 3 articles from the same table:

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE active = '1' ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 0, 3;
```

How can I combine those queries to select 5 articles that are not 3 newest? I do this with PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I wanted was actually this:

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE
FOREIGN_ID_MENU = '".$id."' AND active = '1' AND
date_created < (SELECT date_created FROM article ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 3,1)
ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 0, 5"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION` and use braces for the queries to use the limit for each query

```
(SELECT * FROM article WHERE active = '1' 
AND FOREIGN_ID_MENU != '".$id."'
ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 0, 3)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM article WHERE 
FOREIGN_ID_MENU = '".$id."' AND active = '1' 
ORDER BY date_created DESC LIMIT 0, 5)
```

**EDIT** *from comments*

```
SELECT a.* FROM article a WHERE 
a.FOREIGN_ID_MENU = '".$id."' AND a.active = '1'
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM article aa WHERE aa.active = '1' 
AND aa.id =a.id
ORDER BY aa.date_created DESC LIMIT 0, 3) 
ORDER BY a.date_created DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

Comment: While technically this would work, `LIMIT 5 OFFSET 3` would be *much* simpler and probably more efficient!

Comment: @dvnrrs read OP's question he needs to combine these queries for the conditional 5 articles i.e `FOREIGN_ID_MENU = '".$id."'`  and latest 3 articles

Comment: I see, my mistake. Need more coffee. :-(

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid thank you for your help but your query gives me 8 articles. First 3 of them are the 3 latest, following 5 are from different menus. I need 5 articles from the same menu, but they should not be 3 latest.

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid that also does'nt work. I've figured it out myself - and posted it as an answer. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

If every article has an ID, you can try this :

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  article 
WHERE FOREIGN_ID_MENU = '".$id."' 
  AND active = '1' 
  AND ID NOT IN 
  (SELECT 
    ID 
  FROM
    article 
  WHERE active = '1' 
  ORDER BY date_created DESC 
  LIMIT 0, 3) 
ORDER BY date_created DESC 
LIMIT 0, 5 ;
```